# Can I set the Azure WebJob Dashboard Status myself?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I'm using the Azure WebJob dashboard for monitoring my jobs. I'm not happy with how far I have to drill into the into the interface to determine what's happening. I'd like to leverage the "Status" field on the webjob details page to show if a particular invocation needs attention and in cases where I consider an invocation a failure, even if it didn't blow up.

[image: Azure WebJob Dashboard Status]

I've searched through the Azure WebJobs docs and the features of the Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions package with no luck (but I don't doubt I might have missed it). I manually setting this field possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible but you can have a look at the Kudu APi to create your own dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not happy with how far I have to drill into the into the interface to determine what's happening. I'd like to leverage the "Status" field on the webjob details page to show if a particular invocation needs attention and in cases where I consider an invocation a failure, even if it didn't blow up.

As far as I know, it seems that it does not enable us to set status field by ourselves on Azure WebJob Dashboard. If you’d like to display WebJob run details without clicking into the interface, you could try to call [WebJobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) to get job runs history and retrieve output or error information from logs by requesting **output_url** or **error_url**, and then you could create a **custom dashboard** and populate it with the output and error details data.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't set it yourself.
The Kudu APIs may not give you enough detail for individual function instances. 
Consider putting a feature request on https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/ 
There has been some more investment in exposing a logging API directly over the storage account.